# What is the exact meaning of catuparisa (catu-parisa)?

Tags: terminology, pali-language

The Buddha mentioned *catuparisa* (*catu-parisa)*. What did he exactly meant with this word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the fourfold assembly consisting of *monks, nuns, laymen*, and *laywomen*.

Comment: Is it correct to say that 'catuparisa' is a synonym of the sangha?

Comment: @Guy Well, AFAIK the meaning of pali word 'sangha' in general is group or assembly. But in Theravada specifically, only the ordained monks and nuns are considered as sangha. So I think it's not appropriate to call catuparisa as sangha.